# Can native English speakers read Dickens easily?

Tags: literature

I'm Japanese and I can read Dickens' works now, but with a great deal of effort. It can't be helped, I'm willing to admit btw.

I'm wondering how easily native English speakers can read his works. Is a dictionary necessary because they contain a lot of obsolete words? If so, what dictionary do you prefer when reading his works or other writers' classics?

I'd be glad if you would answer my question.

Comment: I don't think Dickens uses many obsolete _words_, but he often expresses himself in an indirect way and refers to things which are not common knowledge today. I love Dickens, but many people who are not enthusiastic readers find his unabridged works impossibly slow and long-winded.

Comment: I agree that native speakers who are enthusiastic readers should not have too much trouble with Dickens. I vividly remember a summer cold I had aged 9. My mother made me curl up on a sofa and fed me Heinz vegetable soup. For company I had _Great Expectations_.

Comment: I should note: the speech of the convict Abel Magwitch in Great Expectations can be difficult, since it has a fair amount of contemporary slang, informal language, and intentional typos, e.g. "And you know what wittles is?"

Comment: A good technique is to read works that closer in time to Dickens but still more recent.  I find this allows you to build up your reading abilities even for works past him.

Comment: You can read Dickens?  Fantastic. Try to look for Dickens that is annotated with notes that explain antiquated words, idioms and so on. Most importantly keep reading. Keep reading. You will do fine.

Comment: @alphabet - I would hesitate to call 'wittles' an 'intentional typo' (if that is what you meant). Cockneys really did talk like that in those days.

Comment: I would say any native speaker who is educated or reads a lot can read Dickens quite easily (for example, in my class at secondary school everyone studied Great Expectations although I don't know how many people read the entire thing).  I think Penguin Classics version probably has a glossary for the words that are no longer in use or whose meaning has changed.

Comment: @alphabet - _Wittles_ is not a typo, intentional or otherwise. _Victuals_, an old term for food, is pronounced _vittles_, and, as Michael says, apparently in Dickens' time Cockneys often confused 'v' and 'w'.

Comment: Yes, I can. And he is my favorite author. If you start reading early and if you are lucky to have university-educated parents, Dickens is not that hard.

Comment: Your use of "it can't be helped" makes me wonder if you've learnt English in a way that makes things that are easy for natives to understand harder for you,  仕方がない is very Japanese, and it's barely said in English.  Rather than relying on language tools like dictionaries and (for example) duolingo/rosetta stone, consider immersing in the language through media and socialising instead.  There'll be things you don't understand in the moment, but just let them wash over you.

Comment: @Lambie you're essentially stating: "it's all-but impossible for anyone born after 1990"  :)

Comment: In the UK most educated people have some familiarity with Shakespeare and the King James Version of the Bible, from three centuries before Dickens.  The language has changed since they were written, but not to the extent that we can't understand it.  When an unfamiliar word appears we can work it out from the context more often than not.

Comment: @John Yes, and that is true in the US and Canada.

Comment: I should have said "intentional nonstandard spellings intended to reflect nonstandard pronunciations," like "wittles" for "vittles." Of course, then you need to find out what "vittles" means.

Comment: There is a lot of _humor_ in Dickens that may not be appreciated by non-native speakers.  Just as one obvious example:  Character _names_ (surnames) frequently sound funny to native ears - I mean, not "odd" funny but actually laughing-at-it _funny_.  Deliberately so, on Dickens' part.  But if you're not really familiar with what "sounds" to native ears like a funny name ... that'll just slide on by, unfortunately.

Comment: Being a speaker does not an able reader make.  Some have difficulty reading a comic book.

Comment: @KateBunting: I'm far from convinced Victorian Cockneys *did* use **v** instead of **w** the way Dickens always wrote it. I'm sure that even back then, *some* Cockneys would have pronounced the second consonant of, say, ***sorry*** as a ***w*** rather than an ***r***, but conflating ***w*** and ***v*** just seems characteristic of *German* speech. Maybe from Dickens' perspective, all that mattered was the orthography should clearly alert the reader that some character is "low-spoken". Same as current writers have people saying ***sez***, even though phonographically that's totally pointless.

Comment: [This guy](https://youtu.be/V29OhkbzwuQ?t=809) (at 13:29) talks at some length about Victorian novelists and the conflation of Cockney **w** / **v**.

Comment: @alphabet mm, one can only say "Yes, I should have said that ..." when discussing two somewhat similar phrases with similar shades of meaning. You can't say "Yes, I should have said that" when you use a specifically opposed phrase  :)  (It sounds like something I would say after using the wrong term :) )   Any person who doesn't know what vittles is, is either (a) a beginning English learner or (b) was born after about 1995.

Comment: @Fattie I'm in the "born after 1995" category, so that tracks.

Comment: don't feel bad @alphabet - I will die way, way before you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Dickens is generally pretty readable. I can read Dickens without special assistance, but occasionally I would need help with the historical associations, eg this line from *Two Cities*

> France, less favoured on the whole as to matters spiritual than her sister of the shield and trident, rolled with exceeding smoothness down hill, making paper money and spending it

"sister of the shield and trident" is "England (personified by Britannia) and the mention of paper money is in contrast to the gold money used in Britain at that time. Nowadays, "paper money" is common, but it wasn't so at that time. The metaphor of "rolling down hill"  (modern English would have "downhill") refers to the poverty that followed the French revolution.

I would say that I understand more than 99% of the text. But
the language is difficult. It uses figurative language, and rare words like "magnificent potentate" and "wretched pilferer".  I would expect many native children, or most non-native learners to struggle.

For comparison,
Jonathan Swift (Gulliver) I need a good glossary. I understand (perhaps) 95%.  Shakespeare: I need line-by-line help. I understand about 80%.  Chaucer: I understand 50%.  Beowulf: I understand 5%.  Virgil (in Latin) I can probably guess about 1%

For Dickens I'd probably use a regular dictionary, if required.  I would want an edition that had footnotes or similar to help with the historical context. For the older authors I'd use a specialist dictionary, or depend on the notes in the book. Most editions that are "for students" will have supplementary notes.

Comment: As with Twain, dialect speech can be impenetrable to nonnatives: “That’s acause they damped the straw afore they lit it in the chimbley to make ’em come down again,” said Gamfield; “that’s all smoke, and no blaze; vereas smoke ain’t o’ no use at all in making a boy come down, for it only sinds him to sleep, and that’s wot he likes. Boys is wery obstinit, and wery lazy, Gen’l’men, and there’s nothink like a good hot blaze to make ’em come down vith a run. It’s humane too, gen’l’men, acause, even if they’ve stuck in the chimbley, roasting their feet makes ’em struggle to hextricate theirselves.”

Comment: @tchrist that does seem totally impenetrable to nonnatives, though as a native it's actually not too difficult.

Comment: Someone I knew from Spain tried to read ''A Clockwork Orange'' and had to give up as they found it completely impenetrable.

Comment: @ErikE, it can still be easier to understand than actual spoken English. At least I can take my if I need to.

Comment: I read 'Great Expectations' recently and it was a delight - and yes, it was easy for me, a native English speaker, to read.  As you might expect, a few words you have to think about as the comment above mentioned 'wittels' being a corruption of  'victuals' meaning food.

Comment: @AndyClark So long as you know that "victuals" is pronounced "vittles" :)

Comment: @tchrist Difficult to read? Sort of. Impenetrable to non-natives? As a non-native, I don't think so. Reminds me of Feersum Endjinn by Iain M. Banks.

Comment: Actually, paper money isn’t very common these days. Nearly all money is electronic, with only a very small minority being in the form of paper.

Comment: @MikeScott the Bank of England had long been issuing technically paper notes back then, but the pound sterling was backed by gold. So, in this context, I believe paper money refers to the money of which governments can "print" as much as they'd like, which is certainly true for today's electronic money.

Comment: For a native English speaker, reading Dickens' dialectal stuff is real joy because it is so fun to read it out loud and it's easy to get: “That’s because they dampened the straw before they lit it in the chimney //etc.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have a problem with Dickens. He wrote in the mid to late 1800s and, based on the other books I've read from that period it seems written English by that time had already become what we are familiar with as "modern English" - identical in spelling, structure, grammar, form, vocabulary, etc to what we have today.

Anyone who is fairly well read won't have a problem with the vocabulary of Dickens. To be frank I have a much bigger problem with the vocabulary of modern sci-fi writer Jack Vance because he uses obscure words that probably few people were using even in the 1800s.

My guess is any English literature from prior to the early 1800s is going to be substantially different than the modern English that we're used to and would be more difficult.

Comment: I read many 'classics' as a child. I got used to the language and after a while had no more difficulty reading them than more modern works.

Comment: @chasly I think how much being "well-read" will help also depends on what they've read: if they've only read modern American works, the combination of British idioms, unusual/archaic words, and indirect phrasing all would make it very difficult. As native speakers, we have an advantage in that we've almost certainly been exposed to at least one or two of those, and our familiarity with the language lets us intuit meaning based on the flow or rhythm of the sentence. Non-native speakers who don't have any of that cultural foundation, might well struggle considerably more.

Comment: @Aos Sidhe - Yes, I quite agree. We also have access to folklore, metaphors, local knowledge that a non-native may never have met. We certainly have a head start - even as children.

Comment: British Masterpiece Theater, mini-series, TV shows, all help because many of these are based on the older classic literature. I grew up watching these things because my parents were into it, so I'm sure that helped with my ability to read classic British literature (from the mid-1800s+) .... In contrast to this, I do have a very hard time understanding stuff like Shakespeare that was written before 1800.

Comment: [_The History of Tom Jones_](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/6593/pg6593-images.html) is considered one of the first English-language novels (1740), and is not that hard to read, although it might be slower going as you parse through some unfamiliar sentence structures. _Frankenstein_ (1818) and _Jane Eyre_ (1847) are also relatively easy to read. Things get more difficult in the 17th century due to vocabulary and spelling shifts (_A Counterblaste to Tobacco_ is probably a better reference point than Shakespeare). But English prose writing has been fairly consistent since then.

Answer (score 3):

I am also going to say yes and no, the people in this forum who are saying it is easy are a self selecting group of people who are good at English.

I am going to imagine my less bookish friends trying to read it, the language constructs have changed. The imagery has changed so metaphors especially will be difficult. References to social norms won’t immediately click with a modern reader.

Modern readers can find victorian novels too long winded and verbose. With as you say outdated language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Ability to understand isn't the same as ability to read. Think of the difference as the difference between reading the book out loud and the ability to understand what was said. You can have perfect pronunciation, but understand nothing of what is written.

I am taking a couple diversions here, but they relate directly to your question.

### A book I read in Danish

When I was learning Danish *in Denmark*, we had to read Babette's Dinner (Da:Babettes Gæstebud). *Important note: I read this book in Danish.* The understanding of the book can be radically different, depending on your understanding of a few passages. My teacher, an formally trained artist, well educated and intelligent, who's mother tongue is Danish, insisted the guests were sober and the book was only about the difference between values. *It is worth noting, it isn't about the difference between social classes.* I disagreed, and I read up a single passage. *They stumbled and crawled through the snow returning home.* This one point, that they were clearly drunk at the end of the dinner, changed my teacher's understanding of the book.

The assumption is, the native speaker knows best, and I likely misunderstood the passage. However, I read the book with care, and understood if they acted drunk at the end of the dinner, they likely drank a good deal of wine at dinner. It is also supported by a central passage in the book, a drunkenly philosophical passage about beauty through beer goggles. Understanding this point was dependent on how carefully I read the book, and ability to reason if B, then A.

Likewise, Dickens can be understood if you *read the book with care* and are able to make *logical inferences and deductions*. Those are skills that do not automatically come with reading a book in one's native language. Reading the book with care in your second language is one skill you can develop in your native language. Drawing logical conclusions is a different skill you can develop in your native language.

### The American LSAT

Law schools in the U.S. require you have both an undergraduate degree and take the LSAT.

- Any undergraduate degree qualifies

  - B.Sc
  - B.A.
  - B.A.S
- Any major qualifies

  - Pre-Law
  - Any STEM major
  - Any Arts major
  - Any Business major
- The LSAT is the Law School Admission Test

  - Your score is dependent on your ability to reason
  - Your score is dependent on your ability to read
  - Your score ranks you against other applicants
  - Your score is a big factor if you get into law school
  - A lot of information about you is recorded when you take the LSAT
    Because your undergraduate degree and its major is recorded, there is a ranking of majors by score on the LSAT. The common assumption is pre-law, which is the only pathway to study law in most other countries I know about, will take first place by average LSAT score. Truth is, I do not remember if it is even in the top 100 majors, because it certainly isn't in the top 10, top 20, or top 30. Truth is, many arts majors place higher than pre-law. And an important truth is, *the top two majors by LSAT score are mathematics and physics*. The last time I looked at the ranking, those two majors were tied at 160 points.

The lesson here is, legal reasoning is heavily affected by subjects that are the same in all languages. *Reasoning is heavily affected by aptitude other than linguistic skill.* It isn't everyone who can easily reason, or reason at all, so a book such as Dickens may be a difficult read for a native English speaker, while a non-native speaker who can easily reason will find it a light read.

The two skills you need to read Dickens are the ability to read carefully, and ability to reason. Your skill in English is less important.

Comment: You need period vocabulary and class vocabulary and familiarity with British customs. These are sine qua non.

Comment: Discendo discimus. You learn period vocabulary while learning by reading the book itself. Scientia se pascit.

Answer (score 0):

Ampan-san, Well done reading Dickens. I enjoy his books, but they do require a bit of effort. Have you seen this article [Edging Toward Japan: A Straight Line leads from Dicken's London to Murakami's Tokyo](https://mainichi.jp/english/articles/20191221/p2a/00m/0fe/002000c)?

One difficulty is that society has changed a lot since he wrote. Dickens died on 9 June 1870, which would be near the start of the Meiji era. There are words that are unfamiliar, but they often refer to concepts that are unfamiliar: workhouse, debtors' prison, and the like. Dickens wasn't only a successful writer: he was a social reformer, who many things in his own society, such as the shameful treatment of the poor.
Dickens frequently ridicules his bad characters, and exaggerates. You need to understand this when you read him. We have a word "Dickensian", which is used as a criticism: is we say that the conditions for workers is "Dickensian", it indicates disapproval. (Even though Dickens frequently describes happy occasions, we would not use the word "Dickensian" to describe them).
Dickens frequently mocks unpleasant characters by describing them from their own point of view.

Answer (score -5):

This question can't be answered, without noticing the elephant in the room:

**General literacy and linguistic skills, both spoken and written, have tumbled incredibly** in the last 10-20 years, in the English-speaking countries.

If you're talking about people born after (say) 1990, they struggle to read any book.

They can barely struggle through any short, simple novel. Doesn't matter if it's Victorian or not.

The sense of your question is about the grammar, vocab, slang, references, etc, in Victorian novels. For any English speaker born before - say - 1980, it's no issue.

But for the English speaking world, born after say 1990, no, they can't read a Victorian novel (and they can barely read *Harry Potter* or such.)

Recall that people born after about 2000 can't, for example, read a clock with hands, or recite the alphabet or the months of the year. So there's a major break in the answer to your question depending on which historical cohort you're talking about.

Comment: In other news: people born in 2023 can't even talk!  Such a terrible decline.

Comment: This is more a tirade against 'the youths these days' than an answer. "People born after 1990…struggle to read any book. They can barely struggle through any short, simple novel." [Citation Needed] Not to mention that there are plenty of complex (and new) genres: books like House of Leaves or the massively-popular SCP wiki both demand far more of a reader than any Victorian novel, and yet they've become incredibly popular in the past few years—with the latter often *written* by post-90s people.

Comment: I know a lot of people born much earlier who struggle with understanding any short, simple user manual (or even a basic popup message).

Comment: "I see no hope for the future of our people if they are dependent on the frivolous youth of today, for certainly all youth are reckless beyond words. When I was a boy, we were taught to be discrete and respectful of elders, but the present youth are exceedingly wise and impatient of restraint."--Hesiod - c.a. 700BCE

Comment: Look, this is all opinion. But all told, I agree with this 100% and the downvoters are obviously [you fill in the blank] . Cheers. It really gets  up my nose this kind of downvoting.

Comment: the downvoters are all under 20  :)  :) :)

Comment: Downvoting a citation-free claim is good, especially when it wears its ranthood on its sleeve. There's no reason to know how to read an analog clock if you live in a world without them, just like few alive today can run the pre-electric appliances necessary for early twentieth century life.

Comment: Every single answer and comment on here is completely citation-free. (And indeed, the ELL site is often an opinion site, as there are rarely citations for "What do native speakers think" discussions.)  Regarding the clock point, yes, it's correct and general, as you agree. (I have no concern one way or the other whether it's a "good or bad" development, it's a fact and a great example of the staggering stepwise change in literacy, roughly around 1990-2000.